# How to use faker in yii2 in advance template

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am generating random data for project and for unit testing. So i want to use faker. But unable to how to use faker in yii2?

Answer (score 1):

set this in your main config:

```
return [
'controllerMap' => [
    'fixture' => [
        'class' => 'yii\faker\FixtureController',
        'templatePath' => '@common/tests/templates/fixtures',
        'fixtureDataPath' => '@common/tests/fixtures/data',
    ],
    // ...
],
// ...
];
```

use it like this:

```
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

// generate data by accessing properties
   echo $faker->name;
// 'Lucy Cechtelar';
   echo $faker->address;
 // "426 Jordy Lodge
// Cartwrightshire, SC 88120-6700"
    echo $faker->text;
```

for more info check [faker basic usage](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-faker/blob/master/docs/guide/basic-usage.md)
and [yii2 guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-faker/doc/guide/2.0/en/basic-usage)